Invoke-sqlcmd raises exception "Keyword not supported: 'authentication'" while connecting to Azure SQL DB
I receive the following exception while connecting Azure SQLDB with Invoke-SQLCMD PowerShell command.
$conn = 'Server=tcp:MyServer.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDB;Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;Encrypt=True;'
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sys.databases'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString $conn -Query $sql 

Exception:
Invoke-Sqlcmd: Keyword not supported: 'authentication'.

I did some research. It is something to do with MS client libraries:

System.Data.SqlClient
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Looks like the first one needs to be replaced with the second one (don't know how to do that). There are bunch of suggestions for VS Studio and C#, but nothing concrete for PowerShell invoke-sqlcmd command.
I installed .net core framework as well as the latest .net framework. But no luck.
Update:
I noticed that this is a problem only in VSCode! The code works fine in PowerShell ISE

The error is telling you the problem. You, presumably, want Integrated Security=true

Sorry, hadn't noticed it was Azure SQL Database, @Charlieface . Though, I would assume that the OP did still mean Integrated Security with Active Directory Integrated (that it doesn't work with Azure is another issue).

@Charlieface I'm using SQLServer PowerShell module.

@Charlieface I got this:  21.1.18229 sqlserver. So it is coming from SQLServer PS module.

That's over 3 years old, try Update-Module sqlserver

That's the max version we are allowed here. I think the behavior of SQLServer PS module changed since then--things are breaking. There's some research going on in that context, till then we are stuck with the old version.

@Charlieface Interesting find: works from ISE, but not is VSCode!!! Let me update the post!

I'm going to hazard a guess it has the wrong module loaded. Try Remove-Module sqlps; Import-Module sqlserver; I can't help you with business policies: there's nothing wrong with the current version unless you are having issues with certificates, in which case you should sort that out rather than staying on the old version.

@Charlieface with Remove-Module sqlps; Import-Module sqlserver; I could still connect azure sqldb. gcm invoke-sqlcmd in ISE shows SQLServer module. It doesn't look like something to do with SQLServer PS module. It could be something else--ISE being native to Windows and VSC being platform agnostic.

ok. Tried in VSC as well. No luck.

Remember that different versions of PowerShell modules can be installed at the machine level and the current user level (and in DevContainers in VS Code). The SqlServer module switched from the legacy and deprecated System.Data.SqlClient assembly to the modern and supported Microsoft.Data.SqlClient assembly in v22.0.59 back on 2023-04-04. Among other things Microsoft.Data.SqlClient adds new authentication methods for connecting to various Azure resources. Seems that in at least some places you are still running on out of date software and wondering why you cannot connect to Azure.

@AlwaysLearning Good point! I'll work with my team to expedite the upgrade of the module. Thank you so much.

Updating SQLServer PowerShell module to 22.x.x solved the issue. Thank you guys.

Try installing Microsoft.Data.SqlClient In Vs code as below:

Add the extension  Nuget Package Manager GUI .
Then Select the  View  from pull down manual. Choose  Command Palette. In the  Command Palette  select  Nuget Package Manager GUI
.The  Nuget Package Manager GUI  will appear. Select  Install New Package. Type  Microsoft.Data.SqlClient in the search bar then click  Search. Click  Install


Check PowerShell Version in VSCode: Agreed with @AlwaysLearning Ensure that you are using the same version of PowerShell in both VSCode and PowerShell ISE. You can check the PowerShell version in VSCode by running:
PowerShell command:
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Make sure it matches the version you are using in PowerShell ISE.
Make sure you are using the latest version of Visual Studio Code and the PowerShell extension. Updates can sometimes fix compatibility issues.

I could not install data client using Nuget Package Manager GUI. However, updating SQLServer PowerShell module to 22.x.x solved the issue.
